# ASP.NET MVC 4 Create method has null object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have problem with creating object but I don't know why. I have null object in parameter in Post Create method and in ModelState I get this error:

> {System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type
>   'System.String' to type 'BlanskoMenu.Models.ActionOffer' failed
>   because no type converter can convert between these types.    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType(CultureInfo
>   culture, Object value, Type destinationType)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.UnwrapPossibleArrayType(CultureInfo
>   culture, Object value, Type destinationType)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo(Type type, CultureInfo
>   culture)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.ConvertProviderResult(ModelStateDictionary
>   modelState, String modelStateKey, ValueProviderResult
>   valueProviderResult, Type destinationType)}

These are my methods in controller:

```
    //
    // GET: /Action/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var offers = _repository.GetAllActionOffers();
        return View(offers);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Action/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Action/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ActionOffer action)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _repository.CreateActionOffer(action);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(action);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(action);
        }
    }
```

This is my ActionOffer model:

```
public class ActionOffer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my Create view:

```
@model BlanskoMenu.Models.ActionOffer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Vytvořit akční nabídku";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Vytvořit akční nabídku</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Akční nabídka</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImagePath)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImagePath)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
public ActionResult Create(ActionOffer action)
```

to

```
public ActionResult Create(ActionOffer actionOffer)
```